# Can't apply width of div in react

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having a problem of applying the width of my div 50%. Find below my code:

I'm not sure why it's not applying. I can apply the height but can't apply the width.

I have tried vw and vh in width inside tasksContainer and taskContainer but it still doesn't work.

Is there any solution to this?

```
    <div className='tasksContainer'>

            {tasks.map((tasks, index) => (
              <div className='taskContainer'>
                <Form>
                  <Form.Check 
                  className='taskCheckbox'
                  />
                </Form>
                <p>{tasks.name}</p>
                {dateTime}
   
                <div className='taskContainer2'>
                  <Button className='b1'>
                    <Icon disabled name='trash' />
                  </Button>
                  <Button className='b1'>
                    <Icon disabled name='pencil' />
                  </Button>
                </div>
               </div>
            ))} 

    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tasksContainer {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid #ECEDF6;
    background-color: #ECEDF6;
    border-radius: 0.6rem;
}


.taskContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 5vw;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 0.2rem solid white;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;
    background-color: blue;
    accent-color: grey;
}

.taskContainer2{
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}

.taskCheckbox {
    transform: scale(2);
    float: left;
    margin: 1rem;
}


.b1{
   margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

**Image**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the width of ".taskContainer" to be 50%, but after that you overriding it with the "width: 5vw;" which sets a fixed width of 5vw (5% of the viewport width). This might cause the width not appearing as expected.

Just remove  the "width: 5vw;" declaration and keep the "width: 50%;".

Comment: yiep that was my bad trying stuff,still not working ... i gave 100% width in tasksContainer and 50% for each other divs and still it uses only 50%